# Visual Studio Pro 2013 - unable to find XAML Direct3D WP tempate

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013, direct3d

I have been trying to create a XAML Direc3D Project from the Windows Phone 8 & 8.1 project wizard but unable to locate the project template in Visual Studio Professonal 2013!

I have been following this Microsoft article to decide which c# project template would be more suitable to use:

[Choosing the right project template for your game for Windows Phone 8](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/jj662943%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Also following this article explaining the structure of a XAML Direct3D project:

[XAML and Direct3D apps for Windows Phone 8](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/jj207012%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

OK, the problem I'm having is that the XAML Direct3D Project Template is not available from the project wizard options. Maybe I've missed something or have to install additioanl project templates etc?

I have done all the regular searches regarding this but unable to find an answer as yet and hoping someone more experienced here can explain what the problem is here?

Many thanks

Comment: What OS are you running for development?

Comment: @ChuckWalbourn - sorry forgot to mention I'm using Windows 8.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not ay built-in managed assemblies for using Direct3D or Direct2D from C#, so the provided "DirectX and XAML app" project template is a **Visual C++** project.

You should be able to use the standard Visual C# -> Windows Phone apps -> *Blank App (Windows phone)* or Visual C# -> Universal Apps -> *Blank App (Universal Apps)* as a starting XAML app, and then add interop per the MSDN instructions you reference but you'll need to use some other solution for actually calling Direct2D or Direct3D from C# such as [Win2D](https://github.com/Microsoft/Win2D) or [SharpDX](http://sharpdx.org/). For example see the [Win2D docs](http://microsoft.github.io/Win2D/html/Introduction.htm).

Comment: thanks for your reply. I have added interop serveice to my WP app as you said and now need to try and use SharpDX to call the Direct3D. Would you know of any tutorials, samples or documentation that I could read or follow to help with this? J